# Rails Associations - user_id states nil Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am completely unsure where i am going wrong and it surprises me that i can not figure it out, so any advise would be much appreciated.

1. i have 2 models userr(recruiters) & feedbackr(recruiters feedback)
2. [userr model] `userr has_many :feedbackr`
3. [feedbackr model] `belongs_to :userr`
4. [schema] i have added `userr_id` column to the table feedbackrs
5. [feedbackrs_controller] i have added `:userr_id` to the `feedbackr_params`

> the problem is, when i create a feedback comment as a recruiter & go
>   into my console and type `Feebackr.find(4)` (the last created
>   feedback) the `userr_id` shows `nil` -  it
>   is suppose to display the `id` of the userr(recruiter) that created a
>   feedback - i am unsure why it is displaying `nil` as my associations all seem right -

any advise would be much appreciated - i have my files below -

console

```
2.1.2 :055 > ap Feedbackr.find(4)
  Feedbackr Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "feedbackrs".* FROM "feedbackrs"  WHERE "feedbackrs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
#<Feedbackr:0x007fd89136e018> {
                       :id => 4,
                    :email => "richill@gmail.com",
               :created_at => Sun, 28 Jun 2015 00:29:52 UTC +00:00,
               :updated_at => Sun, 28 Jun 2015 00:29:52 UTC +00:00,
    :category_feedbackr_id => 6,
                  :content => "feedback1",
                 :userr_id => nil
}
 => nil 
2.1.2 :056 >
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150627235330) do

  create_table "feedbackrs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_feedbackr_id"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "userr_id"
  end

  create_table "userrs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                    default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",       default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",            default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
  end

  add_index "userrs", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_userrs_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
  add_index "userrs", ["email"], name: "index_userrs_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "userrs", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_userrs_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

feedbackr.rb

```
class Feedbackr < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userr
end
```

userr.rb

```
class Userr < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :feedbackrs
end
```

feedbackr_controller.rb

```
class FeedbackrsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_feedbackr, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @feedbackrs = Feedbackr.all.order("created_at DESC")
    respond_with(@feedbackrs)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@feedbackr)
  end

  def new
    @feedbackr = Feedbackr.new
    respond_with(@feedbackr)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @feedbackr = Feedbackr.new(feedbackr_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @feedbackr.save
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => 'Thank you for your feedback' }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @feedbackr, :status => :created, :location => [@feedbackr] }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @feedbackr.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end  
    end
  end

  def update
    ...
  end

  def destroy
    ...
  end

  private
    def set_feedbackr
      @feedbackr = Feedbackr.find(params[:id])
    end

    def feedbackr_params
      params.require(:feedbackr).permit(:email, :category_feedbackr_id, :content, :userr_id)
    end
end
```

views/feedbackrs/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@feedbackr) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input_field :email, label: 'email address', value: current_userr.email %>
    <%= f.association :category_feedbackr, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'How likely are you to recommend us?' %>
    <%= f.input :content, label: 'What is the primary reason for your score?'%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Provide Feedback' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div><%= render 'shared/footer' %></div>
```

Comment: Hmmm... you don't pass the userr_id information in your form ? Did you mean to assign the `current_user` as the `userr_id` ? You should do this in the controller#create action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to set the `current_user` as the `userr` ?

```
def create
    @feedbackr = Feedbackr.new(feedbackr_params)
    @feedbackr.userr = current_user # And make sure the user is authenticated (though you probably did that in your ApplicationController ?)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @feedbackr.save
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => 'Thank you for your feedback' }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @feedbackr, :status => :created, :location => [@feedbackr] }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @feedbackr.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end  
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `@feedbackr.userr = current_user` in your `feedbackrs_controller.rb` file would automatically generate the user_id field. Since currently, you didn't assign anything to user_id when `feebackr` is being generated, therefore your `userr_id = nil`.